# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I was running my behave feature file through Pycharm.

Each time I executed it ,I am getting below error -

****IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
Process finished with exit code 1****

I have installed Python ,selenium ,behave ,Pycharm as mentioned in site http://www.seleniumframework.com/python-basic/first-behave-step/

used the same steps still I am facing the issue.I tried installing uninstalling several times but no luck.

Can anyone help me and let me know where am I commiting mistake?
Once I proceed I can try other commands also but my problem is I am not able to run the sample code even.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPLEc.png)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @Tankado As you are using `Python` isn't the error clear and concise `IndentationError`? Update the question with your code trials

Comment: The traceback in the picture indicates that the error is not in the file shown in the picture, but in features\environment.py, around line 11. Check the indentation of the lines around there, make sure everything lines up and you're using spaces only OR tabs only.